# Is it possible to invoke a function with a call?

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to make a **view** function (that doesn't modify the state of the chain) that as a result of running would invoke another function, which modifies the state of the chain?

For example, make a function A view, which will return function B()?

My goal is to verify something inside the view function, and only if it's true, initiate the transaction (to save gas).

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a modifier with a condition in it and add it to the function